# SAS display date from TODAY() function

Tags: date, time, sas

In SAS I want to reference the date in MMDDYY form but it keeps spitting out the crazy numbers and not in proper format at all!! I think it is doing the UNIX time.....

Here is what I have after importing the dates from an excel file:

```
date_today = today(); 
put date_today = mmddyy10.;

RUN;
PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

What am I doing wrong>?! please help , thank you so much!!

Comment: You were assigning a _temporary_ format to date_today in your put statement.  The answer by DomPazz applied a permanent dataset format to this variable, which could then be used by the proc print step..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Data foo;
format date_today mmddyy10.;
date_today = today();
run;

proc print data=foo;
run;
```